# Sphinx theme - copy all subfolders inside the static folder

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm developing a theme for Sphinx.
Inside my static folder I have several subfolders, for example `css` with all my css files or `js` for my JavaScript files.
Those are beeing copied on build time correctly.

However if I create a new folder called "sample" inside that static directory, sphinx won't copy it during buildtime to the _static output folder. How can I change that?

Comment: Make sure to define [`html_static_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path) in your `conf.py`.

Comment: That only works for the project, right?
Because the theme itself only has a theme.conf, not a conf.py. Or am I just dumb?